# adb not found al ejecutar AwesomeProject React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Estoy empezando con react, apenas instalando y ejecutando el proyecto que viene en el ejemplo de la pagina oficial, pero al correr la app, indica  que no reconoce el adb:

[image: react native error]

Ya revise los path del sistema, ANDROID_HOME, etc. todo funciona bien,
más bien parece ser un error de sintaxis de React al ejecutar ...\sdk/platform-tools/adb,
¿como puedo cambiar esto?.

---

En las imágenes anexas, probé con el archivo "local.properties" (con el, sin el ,etc).

Aquí probé con una ruta cualquiera para ver si lo respeta.
[image: React Native Error 2]

¿Alguna idea?.

Lo estoy ejecutando en Windows10.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Jerohan ¿corroboraste que el `sdk.dir` es efectivamente donde se encuentra el SDK de Android?
En caso de que no, deberías cambiar el `sdk.dir` para que apunte al path que corresponda.